# How to prove that $\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) \ dx=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I have some trouble to prove that $$\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) \ dx=1\ ? $$

Comment: Doesn't surprise me, because it's false. The integral is less than $1$.

Comment: You have to normalize it... just divide by the integral.

Comment: @Martingalo: no it isn't. The approach to $1$ is from below, and the exponential at $-\infty$ goes to zero.

Comment: Yupp I know, I realized right after pressing "enter" :) I am curious now, can it be transformed into a Gaussian density?

Comment: Ok, that's fine - thanks !

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{-1}^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx$

$=\int_{-1}^0e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx+\int_0^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx$

$=\int_1^0e^{\frac{1}{(-x)^2-1}}~d(-x)+\int_0^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx$

$=\int_0^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx+\int_0^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx$

$=2\int_0^1e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}~dx$

$=2\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{1}{\tanh^2x-1}}~d(\tanh x)$

$=2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{\text{sech}^2x}}~d(\tanh x)$

$=2\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh^2x}~d(\tanh x)$

$=2\left[e^{-\cosh^2x}\tanh x\right]_0^\infty-2\int_0^\infty\tanh x~d\left(e^{-\cosh^2x}\right)$

$=4\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh^2x}\sinh x\cosh x\tanh x~dx$

$=4\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh^2x}\sinh^2x~dx$

$=4\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh2x+1}{2}}\dfrac{\cosh2x-1}{2}dx$

$=2e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh2x}{2}}(\cosh2x-1)~dx$

$=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh2x}{2}}(\cosh2x-1)~d(2x)$

$=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\cosh x}{2}}(\cosh x-1)~dx$

$=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(K_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)-K_0\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 0):

In fact the integral is

$$ e^{-1/2} (K_1(1/2) - K_0(1/2))$$
where $K_0$ and $K_1$ are modified Bessel functions of the second kind.

This comes from Maple 17 after first doing the change of variables $1/(x^2-1) = -s$.

Comment: Yes, I shoud divide by the integral as proposed above by E. T. Thanks for the value.